# How to access with my mobile to an app that use an api that is host in localhost

Tags: api, ionic-framework, localhost, capacitor

Im using an api in order to login in my ionic app.

It works as normal but when I use it in my phone it doesn't work.

When I'm trying to do it, an error appears to the console

`E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/vendor.js - Line 70452 - Msg: ERROR [object Object]`

This is how I use my api

```
var url2 = "http://localhost:3625/api/Filters/LoginEmployee";
```

Im trying to change a line that allows the connection in Manifest but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the APP inside your phone, the http://localhost/vendor.js should be changed to the IP of the computer where the API is running.

If you are testing probably the server is your machine, put both devices, the phone and the computer in the same network to make both available to ping each other.

Verify if your access point is not blocking the 3625 port in the local network.

Comment: ok let me check